# Dart - JS Interop: handsontable Wrapper

Tags: javascript, dart, angular-dart

i am trying to develop a wrapper for handsontable in Angular Dart using pkg.js; I am following this tutorial here:

https://github.com/google/chartjs.dart

I started with a main library method and `Handsontable.Core`:

**JS**:

```
function Handsontable(rootElement, userSettings) {
  var instance = new Handsontable.Core(rootElement, userSettings || {});
  instance.init();
  return instance;
}
```

**DART**:

```
@JS()
library handsontable;

import "dart:html";
import "package:func/func.dart";
import "package:js/js.dart";
import "dart:core";

@JS('Handsontable')
class Handsontable {
      external Handsontable(DivElement rootElement, DefaultSettings userSettings);
} 

@JS('Handsontable.DefaultSettings')
class DefaultSettings {

bool allowInsertColumn = true;
bool allowInsertRow = true;
bool allowInvalid = true;
bool allowRemoveColumn = true;
bool allowRemoveRow = true;
num copyColsLimit = 1000;
num copyRowsLimit = 1000;
bool correctFormat = false;
dynamic currentColClassName = false; //undefined
dynamic currentRowClassName = false; //undefined
dynamic customBorders = false; //false, can be boolean or array
dynamic data = false; //undefined, Can be Array of Array, Array of Objects or Function.
dynamic dataSchema = false; //undefined
String dateFormat = 'DD/MM/YYYY';
bool debug = false;
 // ... omitted code
}

@JS('Handsontable.Core')
class Core  {

external bool get forceFullRender;
external set forceFullRender(bool v);

external Core get instance;
external set instance(Core v);

external String get guid;
external set guid(String v);

external bool get isHotTableEnv;
external set isHotTableEnv(bool v);

external bool get mouseDragOutside;
external set mouseDragOutside(bool v);

external bool get renderCall;
external set renderCall(bool v);

external String get dataType;
external set dataType(String v);
// omitted code
external  getActiveEditor();
external  getCell(e, t, n);
external  getCellEditor(o, r);
external  getCellMeta(e, t);
external  getCellRenderer(e, t);
external  getCellValidator(o, r);
external  getCellsMeta();
external  getColHeader(e);
external  getColWidth(e);
external  getCoords(e);
external  getCopyableData(e, t);
external  getCopyableText(e, t, n, o);
external  getData(e, t, n, o);
external  getDataAtCell(e, t);
external  getDataAtCol(e);
external  getDataAtProp(e);

// omitted code 

external  addHook(String key, f);

Core(DivElement rootElement, DefaultSettings userSettings);
}
```

**JS DefaultSettings**

```
var DefaultSettings = function() {};
    DefaultSettings.prototype = {
    data: void 0,
    dataSchema: void 0,
    width: void 0,
    height: void 0,
    startRows: 5,
    startCols: 5,
    rowHeaders: void 0,
    colHeaders: null,
    colWidths: void 0, // returns undefined? undefined in DART? 
    //omitted code
    };
    Handsontable.DefaultSettings = DefaultSettings; //how can i achieve this in Dart? 
}
```

**Initialization**:

```
  var columns = new JsObject.jsify(this.cols);
  this.ctx = querySelector(div) as DivElement; // suppose to hold root element
  this.settings = new DefaultSettings();
  this.settings.colHeaders = colHeaders;
  this.settings.columns = columns;
  this.settings.data = data; //TODO: cast JsObject to DartObject for the operations
  this.settings.stretchH = 'all';
  this.settings.rowHeaders = false;
  this.settings.columnSorting = true;
  this.settings.minSpareRows = 1;
  this.settings.contextMenu = true;
  this.settings.colWidths = 47;
  this.hot = new Handsontable(this.ctx, this.settings);
```

Now based on the object constructor

```
function Handsontable(rootElement, userSettings) {
  var instance = new Handsontable.Core(rootElement, userSettings || {});
  instance.init();
  return instance;
}
```

The constructor returns `Handsontable.Core`; i tried:

```
class Handsontable {
  factory Handsontable(DivElement rootElement, userSettings) {
     var instance = new  Core(rootElement, userSettings | {});
     instance.init();
     return instance;
  }
}
```

I get error:

```
Class 'Core' has no instance method 'init'.

NoSuchMethodError: method not found: 'init'
Receiver: Instance of 'Core'
Arguments: [...]
```

1. My question is, am i on the right path ?
2. Handsontable.Core have all of the methods, how can i return the "instance" variable from the constructor; Or can i extend Handsontable class from Core, to inherit all properties and methods?
3. In my Dart DefaultSettings class, do i have to provide default values, or will it be interpolated from javascript to dart? For right now, i added default values ... but i could not find Dart 'undefined' value, so i just used false installed instead
4. Everywhere i saw an JSObject datatype i created a separate Dart class in order to convert DartObject to JSObject
5. `Handsontable.Core` does this mean following:

   class Core extends Handsontable {
       Core(DivElement rootElement, DefaultSettings userSettings) : super(rootElement, userSettings)
       }
     }

Comment: I don't have an exact answer for you, so I'll try to help in a comment. Why are you doing anything with "Core"? From the docs for the library, calling the constructor returns an object. That's the only thing you need to be concerned about. When I get a free moment, I'll try it myself and report my experience.